# How show metrics on graph if value is null

Tags: grafana, prometheus

In Prometheus exists some custom metrics from DB

In Graphana I maked Graph Dashboard with datasource from Prometheus

count(custom_metrics_project1<1)

If condition custom_metrics_project1<1 not found any metrics Graphana displays Points not found.

How change condition to be displyed 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select how to display `NULL` values in the edit menu for a given graph.

Please follow these steps:

- click on your graph
- click on `edit` to bring up the edit menu for the graph
- switch to the tag `Display`
- choose one of the options from the `Null Value` dropdown

The option you want is: `null as zero`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count(custom_metrics_project1<1) or on() vector(0)`. This will substitute all the gaps with zeroes. See [docs for `or` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) and [docs for vector() function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#vector).

Note that the `q or on() vector(0)` trick works only when `q` returns a single time series. If `q` returns multiple time series, then Prometheus doesn't provide an easy way to fill gaps in every time series with zeroes :(

If you still need to fill gaps in multiple time series, then you can use `default` operator in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). For example, the following query would fill all the gaps for all the time series returned from `q` with zeroes:

```
q default 0
```

VictoriaMetrics also provides [interpolate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#interpolate), [keep_last_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#keep_last_value) and [keep_next_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#keep_next_value) functions, which can be used for filling gaps in more sophisticated ways.